# Android: Pass html string from java to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

Im building an android app, i have a web server based php page which returns data like

```
{"categories":[{"id":123,"name":"Category 1","img":""},{"id":12,"name":"Category 2","img":""},{"id":56,"name":"Category 2","img":""}]}
```

Now i have managed to use this data in java and get each element i need. Ive read a template file in that has code like:

```
<a class=button id="category_id"><img src="img_path"></img>category_name</a>
```

In Java i am doing string.replace on the contents of this template

```
content += template.replace("category_id", id).replace("category_name", name).replace("img_path", img_path);
```

This is being done in a for loop for each category and is now a string of value:

```
<a class=button id="123"><img src=""></img>Category 1</a><a class=button id="12"><img src=""></img>Category 2</a><a class=button id="56"><img src=""></img>Category 3</a>
```

Now this string when called in javascript like:

```
function showAndroidCategories() {
            var html = Android.showCategories();
            document.getElementById('.button-layout').innerHTML = html;
        }
```

where .button-layout is a div on my webView.
however i get this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (32)
```

which refers to the last line of my javascript you can see above.
All im trying to do is load a list of categories from the data and create a button for each one.

Thanks. Josh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using *button-layout* as a class name (**.**) rather than an ID (**#**).

```
function showAndroidCategories() {
     var html = Android.showCategories();
     document.getElementById('button-layout').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Perhaps this is what you meant to write.

Comment: brilliant spot, i cant believe that the only thing stopping my code from working was '.' :/
I have accepted your answer but i cant vote you up until i have more reputation it seems.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Glad to have helped :)